# How to restrict the user login to Alchemy Webstore

Tags: a4t

How we can control on user login to webstore from Tridion, Is there a way to restrict the user login other than approved.

**Update:**

After we Install Alchemy4Tridion, by default all the users can able to view alchemy and install/uninstall the plugins who has web store account. Instead in current approach, I am trying to restrict the users to access alchemy, based on users who have access to alchemy I wanted to give further Install,uninstall and Configure permissions

Is this achievable in current version(0.8.2)?

Answer (score 8):

In the alchemy control room, it's possible to restrict access of who can install or uninstall plugins via Alchemy.
[image]

To get to this, click the A4T menu, choose "Control room", and then choose "Alchemy Permissions"

If you have a need to block access to the alchemy pages completely, then you could post a request on the github page 
https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/issues, so this could be integrated in an upcoming version of Alchemy.

Comment: For Web 8.5 and above, the Alchemy community could consider if the new Privileges feature could help control visibility via a custom privilege.